# if div is visible, change state of inner text

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Hell,

I have the html code below:

```
<div class="row">
    
    <button id="dog-btn">Show Dog</button>
    <br>
</div>


<div id="pets">
</div>
```

I want some simple code that uses JS to check if the pets div is visible. If it is, the inner text of dog-btn should read Hide Dog. If not visible, it should read Show Dog.

Let me know!

Comment: Based on what criteria? Question is fairly vague and doesn't display any research effort or any attempts to solve your own issue

Answer (score 1):

You can get this by using the .style.display() DOM method.

HTML

```
<div class="row">

  <button id="dog-btn" onclick="showDog()">Show Dog</button>
  <br>
</div>
```

Dog
   
JS

```
document.getElementById("pets").style.display = "none";
function showDog() {
  
   var petDiv = document.getElementById("pets");
   var petBtn = document.getElementById("dog-btn");
   if (petDiv.style.display == "none") {
      petBtn.innerHTML = "Hide Dog";
      petDiv.style.display = "block"
   }
   else {
      petBtn.innerHTML = "Show Dog";
      petDiv.style.display = "none"
   }
}
```

Comment: also make sure you put defer on the script tag or put the code in a `window.addEventListener("load",()=>{ /*code here*/ })` or else the first thing of setting the display to none won't work, as the element hasn't loaded yet when you use getElementById

Answer (score 1):

@DemoNemo5 's answer technically does what your question asks, but i'll assume that you want a button that toggles hiding and showing. Also the previous answer only changes the button once whenever that piece of code is ran.

```js
function togglePets(){
    if(document.getElementById("pets").style.display != "none"){
        document.getElementById("dog-btn").innerHTML = "Show Dog";
        document.getElementById("pets").style.display = "none";
        console.log("hide")
    } else {
        document.getElementById("dog-btn").innerHTML = "Hide Dog";
        document.getElementById("pets").style.display = "block";
        console.log("show")   
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    
    <button id="dog-btn" onclick="togglePets()">Hide Dog</button>
    <br>
</div>


<div id="pets">
    stuff 
</div>
```

we make a function that's called every time the button is clicked, the function checks if the style.display is none (which means it's hidden) and changes the text ofthe button and toggles the display of the pets div

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dog_btn = document.querySelector("#dog-btn");
const pets = document.querySelector("#pets");

dog_btn.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
  pets.style.display = pets.style.display !== "none" ? "none" : "initial";
  dog_btn.innerText = pets.style.display !== "none" ? "Hide Dog" : "Show Dog";
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
    
    <button id="dog-btn">Hide Dog</button>
    <br>
</div>


<div id="pets">
Something
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get the div using `document.getElementById()` in order to access its styles. This code assumes you're toggling the CSS `display` property.

```js
if(document.getElementById("pets").style.display == "none"){
document.getElementById("dog-btn").innerHTML = "Show Dog";
} else {
document.getElementById("dog-btn").innerHTML = "Hide Dog";
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    
    <button id="dog-btn">Show Dog</button>
    <br>
</div>


<div id="pets">
</div>
```